# Java : Parsing Json object to subclass on runtime

Tags: java, json

I have the following POJOs

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class, name = "Child1"),
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class, name = "Child2") 
})
class parent{
 string commonFeaure;
}
class child1 extends parent{
  String child1Feature;

}
class child2 extends parent{
  String child2Feature;
}
```

I have two issues while parsing a Json :

1- My service accept a json object that may be of type child1 or child2, How can do that mapping at the runtime, I have added "@type" at the json but i have to specify the subclass at the mapping like this to map it to child1:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Child1 c = mapper.readValue(jsonInput,Child1.class);
```

How can i make it dyanmic without specifying the cast class at the code ?

2- If a class has an object that is super class to many other classes, while paring the Json object it converted it to the supercalss while @type specify a subclass.

Example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubFeature .class, name = "SubFeature ")
})
class X {
  Feature x;
}
class Feature {
}
Class SubFeature extends Feature {
}
```

In Json i added "@type": "SubFeature" but while parsing it to Java class it parsed to Feature? How can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following annotations on the parent class :

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @Type(value = SubFeature.class, name = "SubFeature")
    })
    class Feature {
    }
```

Then

```
mapper.readValue(jsonInput,Feature.class)
```

should return the correct subclass type.

You will find more information here : [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks @arnaud, Yes i did exactly the same and it parsed it to Feature not SubFeature

Comment: Maybe it is because the class is a top level class in the json. Try creating a wrapper class (say `Features`) that contains e.g a `List<Feature>` , and serialize/deserialize this wrapper instead of directly a `Feature` object.